# Image not found or type unknown (using tinymce with dompdf to show html stored in tinymce textarea in a pdf)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, tinymce, dompdf

I'm using tinymce with image upload using the package "laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload". When the user enters some content in the textarea and clicks the form submit button I want to put the content in the textarea in a pdf file. I have the code below.

The issue is that in the pdf file, if is inserted an image in the textarea, the image doesn't appear in the pdf and in the pdf appears "Image not found or type unknown".

Do you know what can be the issue?

The image is stored like this in the content column of the certificates table:

```
<p>test<img src="/img/image_15zdbBr.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>
```

Code to get the pdf:

```
$certificateContent = RegistrationType::with('certificate')->where('id', $request->registrationType)->first();
$pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($certificateContent->certificate->content);
return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
```

Tinymce code has relative_urls as false:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    plugins: 'image code link',
    relative_urls: false,
    file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        // trigger file upload form
        if (type == 'image') $('#formUpload input').click();
    }
});
```

I already use "setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true])" but also dont works with that, it show the same error.

It seems that the issue can be because is necessary to change the url path of the image. But Im not understanding how to do that since the user only selects a image in the the tinymce textarea how to change the absolute path of that image.

Comment: Try replacing the code with absolute uri like `<p>test<img src="{{ asset('/img/image_1530423144_Yn4tAJwZmzcbb82UOGHo07eIQsiGfzdbBjh10r.jpeg') }}" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>`

Comment: Thanks, do you know where to change that code, in which file of the package?

Comment: Its not file or package it should be inside the content that you pass. If url path doesn't work then try with absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, but Im using tinymce, is only necessary to click in the browse image button and selet an image, so how to change the url path of the image?

Comment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/ - Take a look on this documentation. You will get your answers here.

Comment: Thanks, I already have "                    relative_urls: false,
" as it is in the question but dont works.

Comment: Do you know which url should be in the document_base_url?

Comment: If you use `/img/somename.jpg` as image path, it will be considered an absolute URL. This means if you were to have your website hosted at `https://some.site/vpath/`, it will look for the images at `http://some.site/img/somename.jpg` and not at `http://some.site/vpath/img/somename.jpg` as you'd probably expect. It should also be straight forward to debug if a link generated by your frontend leads to an existing file or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported issue: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1659 .

Suggest you:

1. set relative_urls to true (this will set the image as `img/image_15zdbBr.jpeg`, and
2. set `$dompdf->setBasePath($base_path)` where $base_path is where the files sit. (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#setbasepath)

Edit with salient bits from chat:

1. As you are using a wrapper for Laravel, You need to get a handle on the domPDF class which you will do through `$pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath();`
2. As the relative file path is `../../../image/file.jpg`, this means "start at the "base directory, go back one, go back one, go back one, go into img/, find file". So the "base directory" needs to be ahead of the the files to take accound for the fact you're going back.

Working example:

- Your actual file is located (for real) in `/home/john/projects/proj/public/img/image.jpeg`
- Relative file path (provided) = `../../../img/image.jpeg`
- So you configure your setBasedirectory = `/home/john/projects/proj/public/a/b/c/`
- Combined this gives you `/home/john/projects/proj/public/a/b/c/../../../img/image.jpeg`
- Which is the same as `/home/john/projects/proj/public/a/b/../../img/image.jpeg`
- Which is the same as `/home/john/projects/proj/public/a/../img/image.jpeg`
- Which is the same as `/home/john/projects/proj/public/img/image.jpeg` = Bingo.

If this doesn't work, adjust your setBaseDirectory until you get the right path.

Comment: Thanks, but it appear "Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::setBasePath()
" with " $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper'); $pdf->setBasePath("https://proj.test/img/");".

Comment: You need the pass through: `$pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath("proj.test/img/")`

Comment: Thanks, the image is stored in the database like "<p>abbb<img src="../../../img/image_1531443_Yn7tAZmzcbb82UOGHo07eIctkBjh98r.jpeg" width="1200" height="900" /></p>". But still appear the same error. I also changed the tinymce plugin code to 
              
                    "relative_urls: true" instead of  "relative_urls: false".

Comment: You'll be using the wrong base_path (it should begin `/`, e.g. `/var/www/html/uploads`). To help, what is the full path (in the OS directory) of the file `image_1531443_Yn7tAZmzcbb82UOGHo07eIctkBjh98r.jpeg` you then need to go back one directory (to `img`) and then back up three directories along another tree - any tree - so the base path is actually a directory in advance of the img folder. Bit of a brain scratcher - but you'll get there.

Comment: So your basepath should be `/home/YourUser/projects/proj/public/find/another/directory/` assuming that ~ is `/home/YourUser` (so set this to what it should be). Hopefully that makes sense? You want three down from "public"; any three - doesn't really matter which.

Comment: Thanks, like this  $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath("/home/john/projects/layout/public/img/");?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176259/discussion-between-robbie-and-john).

Comment: thanks, so you are saying that should be something like "$pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath("/home/john/projects/layout/public/img/../../../‌​");"?

Comment: Thanks, but how do i know which are the folders that correspond to the a,b and c in your example?
Im not understanding that.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter. Any three, so long as they exist!

Comment: But it seems that the images are stored in "/home/john/projects/layout/public/img/". So there isnt other directories.

Comment: Like this also dont work, same issue, "        $pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath('/home/john/projects/layout/public/img/'.public_path());
".

Comment: Same issue with "        $pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/img/');
".

Comment: John, please read what I've written and the explanation as to what .. means in a directory tree. Or google it? I can't really add more.

Comment: But with this " $pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/img/'); ", the $pdf variable shows the basepath like "    -basePath: "/Users/john/projects/proj/public/img/". So it seems that is the correct base path, however the pdf downloaded instead of show the image shows "Image not found or type unknown".
"

Comment: Is `"/Users/john/projects/proj/public/img/"``"/Users/john/projects/proj/public/img/a/b/c"` ? Using public_path() is correct, but you still need the "a/b/c" to counter the "../../..". You're not going to avoid that using two conflicting plugins.

Comment: So it should be like "" $pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path().'/../../'); "?

Comment: Even with static html shows the error "Image not found or type unknown". Example: "$pdf->loadHTML('<p>cert1<img src="/Users/john/projects/proj/public/../../../img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>');".

Comment: But like this the image appears "        $pdf->loadHTML('<p>cert1<img src="/Users/john/projects/proj/public/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>');
".

Comment: Like this also works "        $pdf->loadHTML('<p>cert1<img src="'.public_path().'/img/image_1532441196_7GT.jpeg" alt="" width="1200" height="900" /></p>'); But like this the image is static.
".

Comment: John: not a single one of those paths you have put there are what I've suggested. Not one. I really can't explain it any other way: you need to read what's written, or google elsewhere what ../../.. means in a path and how to go up and down a path. But I can't think of any other way to explain other than above. Sorry.