# How to achieve this complex query? (get the certificate(s) content when the user click in "Download Certificate")

Tags: laravel

Im with a doubt how to do a complex query to get the certificate(s) content associated with a registration. Example to explain better the context:

For example the user Jake did a registration with two participants (him and John) in the conference "Conference test 1". The "conference test 1" has two tickets/registration type(s) available (rtype1 and rtype 2) and both registration typeps are free.

In the registration the user Jake selected the registration type "rtype1" for him  and selected the registration type "rtype2" for John.

So after Jake fill in the registration form and click "Register" the database content stays like below.

Database Content:

Conference table:

```
id   name                        ...
1   Conference test 1
```

Registration_types table:

```
id     name     conference_id      certificate_id      certificate_available     price
1      rtyp1          1               1                         Y                   0
2      rtype2         1               1                         Y                    0
```

Certificates table:

```
id    content
1   <p>abbb<img src="https://proj.test/img/image_100.jpeg" width="1200" height="900" /></p>
```

Registrations table:

```
id      conference_id        user_that_did_registration
1           1                            1
```

Participants table:

```
id    registration_id       registartion_type_id       name   
1          1                         1                 Jake     
2          1                         2                 John
```

Then, I have a page that lists all registrations (past and next registrations) of a user in conferences. And if there is a certificate available associated with the registration type(s) of the user registration I show a link "Download certificate":

```
 @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    @foreach($nextRegistration->participants as $participant)
    ....
    @if ($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')
        <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateDownload',[ 'regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"> Download Certificate</a>
    @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And I have the route:

```
Route::get('/certificateDownload/{regID}', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@downloadCertificates',
    'as'   =>'conferences.certificateDownload'
]);
```

**Doubt:**

My doubt is how to properly get the certificate(s) content in the `downloadCertificates()` when the user click in "Download Certificate". Because is necessary to foreach registration, for example, in the example above, foreach `$nextRegistration`, download the pdf with the certificate content of each participant associated with the registration, if the registration_type associated with each participant has "Y" in the certificate_available field (Y means certificate its available).

Im not understanding how the query should be to get this info of the certificates associated with the registration. Can you give a help understanding how this query can be achieved? Im doing like below but its not working Im just getting the info of each registration.

```
public function downloadCertificates($regID)
    {
        //$certificatesOfRegistration = Registration::with('conference.registrationTypes.participants')->find($regID);

        //$pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');
        //pdf->loadHTML($certificateContent);
        //return $pdf->download('certificates.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't store absolute URLs (to your certificates) as this basically binds your database to the server you run on. In my opinion, you shouldn't store the HTML at all but only something like `certificates/cert_001.jpg` which could be stored at `storage_path('certificates/cert_001.jpg')`.

Comment: What do you want to get exactly? An invoice PDF which contains all certificates for a given registration ID? Or is there only one certificate per registration ID? In that case you could just use `Certificate::where('registration_id', $regId)->first()`...

Comment: Thanks, actually the certificate is stored like this "<p>abbb<img src="/img/image_100.jpeg" width="1200" height="900" /></p>". But I also have this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316035/image-not-found-or-type-unknown-get-tinymce-content-in-a-pdf-using-dompdf" that it seems that is necessary to use absolute paths so I changed in the database to use the absolute path for testing purposes.

Comment: I updated the question, changed "invoices" to "certificates". I want to get a pdf with the certificate content for each registered participant associated with the registration. But only for the participants that are associated with a registration type that is associated with a certificate and the column "certificate_available" is "Y".

Comment: Got ya, but where is the reference to `participants` in the `certificates` table?

Comment: No, the participant is associated with a registration type and that registration_type might be or not associated with a certifiacte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our dicussion in the comments, I figure what you want is the following:

```
$regId = 123; // your registration id

Certificate::whereHas('registrationTypes', function ($query) use ($regId) {
        $query->where('certificate_available', 'Y')
            ->whereHas('participants', function ($query) use ($regId) {
                    $query->where('registration_id', $regId);
                });
    })
    ->get();
```

---

**Edit:** with the new information, that we want one certificate per participant (if one is available), we should now use something like the following

```
$regId = 123; // your registration id

$participants = Participant::where('registration_id', $regId)
    ->whereHas('registration_type', function ($query) {
        $query->where('certificate_available', 'Y');
    })
    ->with('registration_type.certificate')
    ->get();
```

This will give you a list of participants, which have a registration type that comes with a certificate. Only participants with a certificate available will be loaded. You can access the certificate like this:

```
foreach ($participants as $participant) {
    $certificate = $participant->registration_type->certificate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows undefined cosntant participants.

Comment: I fixed a typo (missed a quote `'`). Please try again.

Comment: Thanks, now it shows "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::registrationTypes()
".

Comment: Certificate model: "class Certificate extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['content'];

    public function registration_types(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'certificate_id');
    }
}
"

Comment: Well, simply change the relation name from `registrationTypes` to `registration_types`. If you'd follow the naming conventions, above would have worked. :)

Comment: Thanks, like that it works, but for example the registration with id 3 has two participants associated and one participant is associated with the registration type "rtype1" and other is associated with the registration type "rtype2". When the user clicks in "download certificate" it should download a pdf with the two certificates content since both registration types (rtype1 and rype2) have a certificate associated and certificate_available is "y". But in the pdf only appears the content of the certificate 1, do you know why?

Comment: Well, it is the same certificate, so I assumed you only want it once. Do you need the certificates once per participant, once per registration type or once per certificate type?

Comment: Thanks, it should be once per participant, that is, if the registration has two participants for example and both are registered in registration types that have certificates associated it should appear the content of the two certificates in the pdf. Like that is possible to show in the first page of the pdf the certificate with the name of the first participant and the registration type and in the second page of the pdf the second participant name and the the registration type associated with the participant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176268/discussion-between-namoshek-and-john).